# Headers variable double definition

Tags: c++, header-files

With the following files, I get the error `multiple definition of 'a'` even though I only defined it once?

header.cpp

```
add (int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
}
```

header.h

```
#if !defined(header)
#define header

int add (int x, int y);

int a;

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
#pragma once

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main() {
    cout << "hi" << endl;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

The code is copied exactly

Comment: [Declaring variables in header files C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942013/declaring-variables-in-header-files-c)

Comment: It does help if you provide actual code.  As provided, your code will not result in multiple definitions (and will not compile either).

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you didn't include header.h in header.cpp? I suspect that you did.

Comment: *I get the error* -- Is this a compiler error, or linker error?  If you included `header.h` in both `header.cpp` and `main.cpp`, then that is a linker error, not a compiler error.  So did you post the entire `header.cpp` file?

Comment: And, BTW, `#pragma once` is unnecessary with an include guard.   But, if you do use it, use it in header files, not source files.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I get the error when compiling